# vs2008 setup project "start" user interface add dialog disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dialog, setup-project

In vs2008, I have a modified dialog that I want to add to the setup process.  However, the "Start"->"Add Dialog" option is disabled.  Only the administrative install allows to add a dialog to it.  I haven't created the administrative dialog equivalent yet, so that isn't going to really help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the added dialogs I was working on from the vsdialogs folder, restarted vs2008, and added them back.  "Add dialog" is enabled.